# What is the problem with my Insertion sort

Tags: java, arraylist

I have gone through my code for an hour and still can't figure out what is wrong:

```
void insertionsort(List data) {
        for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i ++) {
            number2 = (Comparable) data.get(i);

            int holder = i-1;

            while (holder > 0 && (number2.compareTo(data.get(holder)) < 0)) {
                data.set(holder, data.get(holder-1));
                holder-=1;
            }
            data.set(holder, number2);
        }
```

Comment: 1) This is not vanilla JS as far as I can tell. 2) What inputs are you giving the function? 3) What output is the function giving for those inputs?

Comment: Java !== JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code.

1. Loop never checks first item in list. Check `holder > 0` Lists in Java always starts at index 0. When your holder is set to 0, the while loop never runs. Changing it to  `holder>= 0`  will fix this problem.
2. Switching the wrong items. You want to compare `number2` with everything that comes before it in the list. If `number2` is smaller than something previous, you need to shift over all your previous items. `holder` is already pointing to an item before `number2`. Which means you'll need to shift each `holder` with whatever is held in `holder+1`
3. Inserting `number2`. The code as is, you're setting `number2` into a position one less than it should be in. You need to set `number2` in position `holder+1`

I'd recommend https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/ to check up on the fundamentals of insertion sort.